# Android 9-patch not working as expected

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a 9-patch png for a Spinner, but the image isn't stretching as expected. I used Android Asset Studio.

Here's what the Spinner looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/shHr6.jpg

and here's what the 9-patch looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuT1h.png

The placement of the image is correct (it should be in the bottom right of the spinner), but I'm not sure why the color distortion is occurring (I want the entire spinner to be white).

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 9-patch is the problem. Looks like you downscaled this from a larger source? During the downscaling, your edge pixels were aliased:

[image: Bad 9-patch]

So your stretch points are actually on semi-transparent pixels. Just fix those edge pixels to be white again and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I created the image in illustrator and exported it to .png (I no longer have the image vector). Was this an improper way to do it/is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Surely you didn't make the 9-patch border in Illustrator? All you need to do is take your image into Photoshop and change the top row and left column pixels of the image to white. If you look below your stretch points (pixels 0,1 and 1,0) you'll see that the rows/columns they represent are gray, not white.

Comment: Gotcha. Much appreciated.